# Using Highcharts (and modules) with lit-element

Tags: javascript, highcharts, polymer, es6-modules, lit-element

According to a [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/11180), this is a follow-up question:

I want to use Highcharts and some modules with Lit-Element and struggle during the import of Highcharts and modules.

If I use `import 'highcharts';`, I can perfectly use the `Highcharts`-Object in my code. With the given solution (`import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';`), it doesn't work.

Neither does any of the given module import solutions work:

```
import 'highcharts/modules/exporting'; // doesn't throw an error, but can't bind it to Highcharts

import HC_exporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting'; // does throw a 'no named default export' error

import * as HC_exporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting'; // throws 'TypeError: HC_exporting is not a function'
```

```
ld-application-actions.js:56 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: The requested module '../../../../node_modules/highcharts/modules/exporting.js' does not provide an export named 'default'
```

So is there any possibility to **import and use** Highcharts and it's modules?

Crazy thing: I tried to create an example on Stackblitz, but there it works: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ic7f4z

What's the difference here? Is that because Stackblitz uses a TypeScript import and I use `polyserve` without TypeScript?

**Update:**

I created the same example on JSFiddle (see https://jsfiddle.net/sebastianroming/uer59cnw/6/) and here's the same as on my machine: doesn't work. Feel free to uncomment the commented lines to get the console's output.

Thanks!

Comment: did you try `import Highcharts from 'highcharts';` and use `Highcharts.chart('id_chart', {option Object} )` as usual ? I did it with my project and it works

Comment: @DucHong Yes, I tried, but: `The requested module '../../../../node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.js' does not provide an export named 'default'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `lit-element` and `polyserve` Highcharts and its modules can be downloaded like that:

```
import 'highcharts';
import 'highcharts/modules/exporting';
import 'highcharts/modules/boost'
import 'highcharts/highcharts-more';
```

**Component code:**

```
import { LitElement, html } from 'lit-element';

import 'highcharts';
import 'highcharts/modules/exporting';
import 'highcharts/modules/boost'
import 'highcharts/highcharts-more';

class ChartTest extends LitElement {

  firstUpdated(changedProperties) {
    this._enableChart();
  }

  render() {
    return html`
      <div id='container' style='width:500px;height:300px;border: 1px red solid;'>sfsdfs</div>
    `;
  }

  _enableChart() {
    Highcharts.chart(this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#container'), {
      xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
          'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'
        ]
      },
      series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        type: 'column'
      }]
    });
  }

}
customElements.define('chart-test', ChartTest);
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rwec7b6o/1/

Comment: Awesome - didn't think it could be that easy! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your `tsconfig.json` needs to include:

```
"esModuleInterop"             : true,
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
```

See: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

After TypeScript is configured this way, the following should work:

```js
import * as HC_exporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting';
```

Comment: Thanks - but i *don't* use Typescript, so I don't have a tsconfig.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation the exporting library is called Exporting:
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/#toc7

```
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
// Alternatively, this is how to load Highstock. Highmaps and Highcharts Gantt are similar.
// import Highcharts from 'highcharts/highstock';

// Load the exporting module.
import Exporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting';
// Initialize exporting module. (CommonJS only)
Exporting(Highcharts);

// Generate the chart
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  // options - see https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts
});
```

Since you are using Lit Element I assume you have Webpack installed as well, which allows you to use it differently as can be seen here: 
https://gist.github.com/jon-a-nygaard/f22ade93209277eea5b57c0f6ca51ea7

Comment: Thanks for this hint - yet I stumbled over this already, but I don't use webpack, tho. I use `polyserve`, nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [highcharts webcomponent](https://github.com/ashubham/highcharts-webcomponent). Which is a convenience wrapper over highcharts. (Its internally implemented using Lit)